# Doc type breaking my css, why?

Tags: html, css, doctype

Why does adding doc type break this layout? How can I make this better?

**JSFIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/3gA7u/1/**

HTML

```
<body>  
    <div id="maincontainer">
        <div id="leftcolumn">left</div>

        <div id="contentwrapper">right</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
}

#maincontainer {
width:100%;
height: 100%;
}

#leftcolumn {
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width: 510px;
height: 100%;
background: orange;
}

#contentwrapper {
position: fixed;
float:left;
display:inline-block;
width: -moz-calc(100% - 510px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 510px);
width: calc(100% - 510px);
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/3gA7u/1/**

Comment: Adding a `DOCTYPE` is probably *fixing* your layout (as it is with your current CSS), and you were thinking its state without one was "working", when in fact it was probably considered broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have `min-height` on html, body. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3gA7u/2/

Comment: What has this to do with the question?

Comment: @MikeW "Why does adding doc type break this layout? How can I make this better?" didnt he wanted to have the left column to `100%` height? what is your problem with my answer anyway?

Comment: @n1kkou - What's wrong with your answer is that it's not the min-height setting that's making the left column have 100% of the viewport height, but the other change you made to the fiddle - giving the html element `height:100%`.